# openstack nbd15 error information

Tags: openstack

I am trying to do an openstack deployment according to the book "openstack clouding computing cookbook2012". I did everything exactly the same as the book. Everything was fine until I ran the command: 
euca-run-instances ami-00000002 -t m1.small -k openstack
to start an openstack instance.

After I ran this command, euca-describe-instances showed that the instance status was pending at first. But after a while, at the openstack computing node, I saw error message saying:
block nbd15: receive control failed (result -32)

Then euca-describe-instances showed the instance status was error.

I tried twice of the whole process (I mean start over from installing virtual machine), and the same result.

Can anybody help? I am now stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to request clarification, but what version of OpenStack are you using and what was the exact error message (please include the whole long line, perhaps with some context)? The text "receive control failed" does not appear in the nova codebase.

Comment: I just ran the command:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install rabbitmq-server nova-api nova-objectstore
nova-scheduler nova-network nova-compute nova-cert glance qemu
unzip
to install openstack. The version should be the latest release of openstack. 

For the error message, it was all the information that was shown on the screen of the openstack computing node. I tried to start the instance at a client with euca tools.

Comment: The version of the distro you're using will affect what version of OpenStack you have installed, as will whether you have the cloud archive enabled. Please provide the contents of /etc/lsb-release and the contents of /var/log/nova/nova-compute.log where the error occurs.